# texture vs texture2D in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

When sampling a 2D texture in GLSL (a `uniform sampler2D`), the `texture` function is used and the dimension is inferred from the sampler (2D in this case). This is the modern way of sampling a texture in the GLSL since 1.30 ([GLSL Reference Pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/)). However you can also use the `texture2D` function.

Is the `texture2D` function deprecated and if so, will support for the `texture2D` function be removed (or has been removed) in some version of GLSL?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, `texture2D()` is deprecated as of (at least) OpenGL 3.3; see page 99 of the [3.30 GLSL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.3.30.6.clean.pdf). It will continue to be supported in OpenGL compatibility profiles to avoid breaking existing code, but its usage in new code is strongly discouraged.

**EDIT**: The details are slightly different for OpenGL ES, but the end result is the same: `texture2D()` was deprecated and replaced by `texture()` in OpenGL ES 3.0; see section 8.8 of the [3.0 GLSL ES specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.3.pdf).

Comment: There was no mention of OpenGL ES in the original question, so I assumed we were talking about vanilla GL. If the answer is different for GL ES, that's certainly worth mentioning; I'll update my answer (unless somebody else wants to chime in).

Comment: @Jessy Considering that the question didn't mention any ES (which doesn't even have deprecation, not to speak of GLSL 1.30 or the `texture` function as **mentioned explicitly in the question**), your comment doesn't really make sense. The fact (or is it one anyway?) that most people use OpenGL ES doesn't magically make this perfectly correct answer senseless. Because you expect an off-topic answer (for whatever reasons) doesn't suddenly make an on-topic answer off-topic.

Comment: So is the answer to this use 'texture()' if on OpenGL and 'texture2D()' if on OpenGL ES? I would have preferred for there to be one function.

Comment: There are two kind of people: those, who expect to give answers to the question exactly as it was asked, and those, who expect to get answers to a question they had in their mind. And sometimes those two are actually the same kind of people.

Comment: @JanieClayton The original question never mentioned any iOS or other OpenGL ES. The `ios` tag was added by some other user (for reasons I have no idea about).

Comment: they should make this preprocessor thingy replace all instance of texture2D() with equivalent texture() calls