# How to draw a YUV texture with delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

As far as I Know YUV texture is a composition of 2 textures (the Y and the UV). Those 2 textures must be drawn on the canvas using a shader like this one :

```
#version 100
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 vUV;
    uniform sampler2D SamplerY;
    uniform sampler2D SamplerUV;

    void main() {

        mediump vec3 yuv;
        lowp vec3 rgb;

        yuv.x = texture2D(SamplerY, vUV).r;
        yuv.yz = texture2D(SamplerUV, vUV).rg - vec2(0.5, 0.5);

        // Using BT.709 which is the standard for HDTV
        rgb = mat3(      1,       1,      1,
                         0, -.18732, 1.8556,
                   1.57481, -.46813,      0) * yuv;

        gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1);
    }
```

I know how to use a shader with one texture, however I don't know how I can use a shader with **2 textures in parameters**

Comment: This kind of question would probably be more at home somewhere like here: https://en.delphipraxis.net/. You might also want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307278/texture-vs-texture2d-in-glsl#12309212

Comment: @DaveNottage: I did: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/426-how-to-draw-a-yuv-texture-with-delphi/  ... but I don't understand why this article:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307278/texture-vs-texture2d-in-glsl#12309212

Comment: Because your example code in this question is using texture2D, which is deprecated.

Comment: @DaveNottage: all openGL is deprecated in ios (arrrrrgh i still can not believe it!)

Comment: Yeah, there is that, too ;-)