# How do I tell QtCreator to accept the `texture()` function like it did for the `texture*D()` functions?

Tags: glsl, qt-creator

I am using QtCreator 4.12 as a generic C++ IDE, installed from my distribution's package manager, so this is a generic question about QtCreator usage, not related to Qt in particular, nor building QtCreator from source.

Like any IDE, QtCreator highlights potential errors while writing code.
in a .cpp file, if I write `int x = 0` and press enter, the 0 will be underlined in red, and there will be a tooltip telling me that I forgot the `;` at the end of the line.

This is described [in the QtCreator documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html), but I couldn't find anything in that documentation about GLSL.

My actual project is a C++ with openGl game, and I'm editing my GLSL shaders within QtCreator.

Reading the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307278/texture-vs-texture2d-in-glsl) question, I've learned that all the `texture*D()` functions were deprecated since openGL 3.3, and have to be replaced with `texture()` which infers the texture dimension, so I decided to update my shaders.

Within QtCreator, when I use the `texture()` function, the whole line gets underlined with red color, with a tooltip saying *expression too complex*, whereas when I use `texture2D()` (or `texture1D()` or else), the line isn't underlined as shown in following pictures :

- deprecated GLSL:
  [image: legacy GLSL code]
- non-deprecated GLSL:
  [image: modern GLSL code]

This doesn't prevent my shaders to work as designed at all, so there's no real problem here, but it's really disturbing.

I don't know anything about the syntax error checking mechanism more than what is written in the linked documentation page, and I'm looking for a way to change this mechanism to accept GLSL 3.3+. I would accept an answer telling me how to silence this specific false positive as a workaround, or a way to deactivate the syntax error checking for .glsl files, but I would really prefer to understand how I could tweak the error checking mechanism to accept modern glsl as it does for legacy glsl.

Comment: First thing to understand is that QtCreator has nothing to do with GLSL. Are you compiling QtCreator source code or what? If not - then clarify what actually you are trying to do (like coding application using QtWidgets / QtQuick / SDL / whatever, with real code quoted). QtCreator is just an IDE like Visual Studio and others helping you to edit source code and build it with compilers.

Comment: I will edit the question to clarify my intention.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you are talking about QtCreator syntax highlighting - didn't know it supports GLSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I wrote a bug report : [QTCREATORBUG-24068](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-24068).

There's a patch addressing the issue, which I could test. It will be merged in QT Creator's source v4.14.